# MMGIS not able to connect to maps.googleapis.com

Tags: qgis, geocoding, mmqgis

I've been trying to geocode a few addresses from a .csv file to a shapefile.  Been using MMQGIS on Qgis, but, even though I seem to have everything set up properly, I continually get the error message that there was a failure to connect to maps.googleapis.com and therefore it fails to geocode any of the addresses from my excel spreadsheet.  Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: Still working over here... maybe make sure the plugin is up to date...?

Comment: Define 'a few' :-) Is it possible you tried to geocode too many points and went over [the API usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits)? You might want to retry again in a while (in case of temporary outage), perhaps with a subset of your data (in case it's API limits).